# Planting Birch trees in the forest?

Tags: trees, tree-care

I would like to buy 1000 Birch trees, to plant them in the forest. Can they grow without water? because I read that they need a lot of water.

In my country - occupied Palestine - it only rains in the winter. And the temperature in the summer is from 25 -35 C.

Comment: I feel from my experience watching birch trees die that the dry time would be too long. Also, look around for other trees that grow in Europe(oaks etc), do you see any? Probably not, because it’s too dry.

Comment: If there's ground water they can reach, that's one thing - but transplants almost always need watering until they become established. Also - planting them in a forest they would likely be shaded out by mature trees. If you mean planting them *to make a forest,* they would probably need some shade, and supplemental water, to become established. Seems likely too dry for too long to have much chance...